# jQuery toggle menu, default hidden below x pixels, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#nav").hide();
    $("#toggle-nav").click(function () {
        $("#nav").slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

And this one for HTML:

```
<button id="toggle-nav">...</button>
<nav id="nav">...</nav>
```

... which is great for I can toggle the menu for mobile-sized screens.

My new problem is that I don't know how to set a screen width starting point for the default hiding of the menu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/media-max-width/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/emkmtfs5/1/

Comment: That actually is the most simple and working set as it keeps css together. If you posted this here as an answer I would mark as best answer for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one option is to use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) like

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    #nav {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/emkmtfs5/)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to handle different screen sizes is to use media queries in CSS,but if your doing this with Jquery then use :-

`$(window).width()` in Jquery.

Read more here:- http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: Thanks Exception, In fact I should use css as in Arun's comment, I will keep that in mind though!

Comment: @BenedictGagnon..yes..that is that first line of my answer is also saying .. handle this in css only...thankzzz.....